# Нейросеть с обучением на json данных

Tags: json, алгоритм, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, big-data

Есть задача создать нейросеть с обучением на json данных.
Подскажите плиз в какую сторону копать (тип нейронки, ссылки и т.п.).

Пример данных на вход:

```
{
   "a": [...],
   "b": {
     "result_0": 2,
     "result_1": [1,2,3],
     "result_2": {
       "subres_0": "val0",
       "subres_1": "val1"
     }
   },
   "c": "val3"
}
```

Набор данных будет приблизительно такой.
Под "a" может быть как пустой массив так и нет, причем вес этих элементов может сильно различаться в зависимости от содержимого.

Я не прошу ни в коем случае готовое решение.
Будет достаточно указать какой тип сети (сверточная или др.), примеры/линки на обучение на json данных (с неизвестной структурой дерева) и т.п.

Comment: Искал инфу по обучению на json'ах, но нашел только распознавание json в строке и другие, не относящиеся к данной задаче, описания и гайды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то у вас все в кучу.

Тип сети вообще никак не зависит от того, в каком виде данные вам задаются.
Все с точностью до наоборот - сначала вы анализируете задачу (и это, разумеется, не задача обработки JSON-данных. Формализация идет практически в терминах вашей предметной области). Потом под эту задачу выбираете тип сети. А уже потом думаете, как данные, которые оказались в JSON (точно так-же, как они могут оказаться в CSV, в TXT, в XML, да в любом известном формате, хоть в бинарном) преобразовать к виду, который требуется для вашей сети. И да, как правило (но не всегда) это будет таки 2D матрица.
Для лучшего понимания (и если вы работаете в TensorFlow - попробуйте посмотреть еще вот сюда:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381887/how-to-read-json-files-in-tensorflow

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_json_example

Если работает с другими библиотеками - там "рекомендации" могут быть немного другими, но суть останется также.

Но моя рекомендация все таки - начать с азов, с изучения того, как-же строятся нейросети, как они представляют данные, что-такое формат представления данных и как все это понятия связаны между собой.

P.S. Кстати, фраза "вес (???) этих элементов может сильно различаться в зависимости от содержимого" для меня вообще осталась более чем загадочна. В нейронных сетях "вес" - это значение коэффициентов, с которыми данные передаются от одного слоя к другому. А что это означает у вас?

Comment: Массив под ключем "а" может быть наполнен объектами, содержимое которых может быть разным и сильно будет влиять на результат обработки всего json. Но я понял, что это не проблема нейросети (сможет ли она отличить эти элементы и в зависимости от их наполнения, расставить правильно веса "входному" слою), а проблема упаковки данных в матрицу.    Спасибо большое за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Все известные мне нейросети работают с числовыми матрицами в качестве входных данных. Размерность матрицы может различаться в различных ИНС (Искусственная Нейронная Сеть), но в каждом образце/экземпляре данных должно присутствовать одинаковое количество значений. Т.е. если у нас входная матрица размерности `(1000 x 50)`, то каждый образец данных имеет ровно 50 входных значений - ни больше ни меньше. Чтобы достичь этого часто пользуются выравниванием - выбирается максимальное число признаков например `50` и либо отбрасываются лишние признаки (обычно мало влияющие на результат) если таковых больше 50-ти либо наоборот добавляются нулевые значения, если значений меньше 50-ти, чтобы в итоге получить ровно 50 входных значений для каждого образца данных.

Именно так работает функция [keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences()](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/), которую часто применяют для векторизации текстов. Ведь тексты могут сильно различаться по размеру.

Я думаю вам придется нормализовать ваши JSON данные таким образом, чтобы получить прямоугольную `2D` матрицу состоящую из целых или вещественных чисел.